# HAProxy, session sticky and balance algorithm

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I got a HAProxy with basic configuration as below:

```
frontend fe_http
 bind *:80
 default_backend be_http
 capture request header AWESOME-HEADER len 40

backend be_http
 mode http
 option forwardfor
 balance hdr(AWESOME-HEADER)
 stick-table type string len 40 size 5M expire 1m
 stick on hdr(AWESOME-HEADER)
 server s1 x.x.x.x1:8080 check
 server s2 x.x.x.x2:8080 check
```

According to **balance hdr(AWESOME-HEADER)**, requests with same AWESOME-HEADER will go to same server, and my test confirms that.

This is so called "session sticky", right? So, do we still need **stick-table** and **stick on** lines? (I do try to remove these 2 lines, and HAProxy still performs like session sticky as I expected)

Thanks.

Comment: in case anyone jumps here looking for an answer, i found one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583337/haproxy-session-sticky-and-balance-algorithm